# Spreadsheets keys converter

Tags: c++, c++14

i was trying to solve [this](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1/B) problem. as it mentions:

> In the popular spreadsheets systems (for example, in Excel) the
>   following numeration of columns is used. The first column has number
>   A, the second — number B, etc. till column 26 that is marked by Z.
>   Then there are two-letter numbers: column 27 has number AA, 28 — AB,
>   column 52 is marked by AZ. After ZZ there follow three-letter numbers,
>   etc.
>
> The rows are marked by integer numbers starting with 1. The cell name
>   is the concatenation of the column and the row numbers. For example,
>   BC23 is the name for the cell that is in column 55, row 23.
>
> Sometimes another numeration system is used: RXCY, where X and Y are
>   integer numbers, showing the column and the row numbers respectfully.
>   For instance, R23C55 is the cell from the previous example.
>
> Your task is to write a program that reads the given sequence of cell
>   coordinates and produce each item written according to the rules of
>   another numeration system.
>
> the exercise is to write c++ program by using standard input/output.
>   and allow the user to pass entries and convert those value to its
>   corresponding values
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line of the input contains integer number n (1 ≤ n ≤ 105), the number of coordinates in the test. Then there
>   follow n lines, each of them contains coordinates. All the coordinates
>   are correct, there are no cells with the column and/or the row numbers
>   larger than 106 .
>
> **Output**
>
> Write n lines, each line should contain a cell coordinates in the other numeration system.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> 2 
> R23C55 
> BC23
>
> Output: 
> BC23 
> R23C55
> ```

Here my attempt solution, it works as expected, i have slightly change the input to make it interactive.
All inputs are guaranteed to be **valid** and **correct** as well as the result.

How can I improve it further.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <cctype>
#include <limits>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

// C::B : error: 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'!
int string_to_int(std::string::const_iterator first, std::string::const_iterator last)
{
    int value = 0;
    if(first == last) return value;

    const typename std::string::value_type sign = *first;
    if (*first == '-' || *first == '+')
        first++;

    while (first != last)
    {
        value = value * 10 - (*first++ - '0');
    }

    if (sign != '-')
        value = -value;

    return value;
}

int is_RC_type(const std::string& in)
{
    const auto index = in.find_first_of("C");
    if (index == std::string::npos) return false;

    const auto row = in.substr(1, index - 1);
    const auto col = in.substr(index + 1);

    static const int Min = 1;
    static const int Max = 999999;

    const auto colVal = string_to_int(col.cbegin(), col.cend());
    const auto rowval = string_to_int(row.cbegin(), row.cend());

    return col[0] != '0'
            && row[0] != '0'
            && rowval >= Min
            && rowval <= Max
            && colVal >= Min
            && colVal <= Max
            && std::all_of(row.cbegin(), row.cend(),
            [](char c)
            {
                 return std::isdigit(c);
            })
            && std::all_of(col.cbegin(), col.cend(),
            [](char c)
            {
                 return std::isdigit(c);
            });
}

bool is_Cell_type(const std::string& in)
{
    const auto index = in.find_first_of("0123456789");
    if (index == std::string::npos) return false;

    const auto row = in.substr(0, index);
    const auto col = in.substr(index);

    static const int Min = 1;
    static const int Max = 999999;

    static const std::string alphaMin{"A"};
    static const std::string alphaMax{"BDWGM"};
    static const auto AMin = string_to_int(alphaMin.cbegin(), alphaMin.cend());
    static const auto AMax = string_to_int(alphaMax.cbegin(), alphaMax.cend());

    const auto colVal = string_to_int(col.cbegin(), col.cend());
    const auto rowval = string_to_int(row.cbegin(), row.cend());

    return  col[0] != '0'
            && colVal >= Min
            && colVal <= Max
            && rowval >= AMin
            && rowval <= AMax
            && std::all_of(col.cbegin(), col.cend(),
            [](char c)
            {
                 return std::isdigit(c);
            })
            && std::all_of(row.cbegin(), row.cend(),
            [](char c)
            {
                 return std::isalpha(c);
            });
}

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
std::enable_if_t<std::integral_constant<bool, B>::value, T>
conditional(T&& t, F&&)
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

template <bool B, typename T, typename F>
std::enable_if_t<!std::integral_constant<bool, B>::value, F>
conditional(T&&, F&& f)
{
    return std::forward<F>(f);
}

template <typename Input, typename Prompt>
Input read_input(Prompt&& prompt)
{
    static_assert((std::is_integral<Input>::value && !std::numeric_limits<Input>::is_signed)
    || std::is_same<std::decay_t<Input>, std::string>::value, "type not supported!\n");

    Input input{};
    bool is_not_valid = false;

    static const std::string Error = "Not valid input.\n";
    static const std::regex Letters("^[A-Z0-9]+$");
    static const std::regex Numbers("^[0-9]+$");

    static auto int_input = [] (auto& in, std::istream& is = std::cin)
    {
        std::string s;
        std::getline(is, s);
        std::stringstream stream(s);
        return  is.fail()
                || !std::regex_match(stream.str(), Numbers)
                || !(stream >> in)
                || (1 < in && in > 100000);
    };

    static auto string_input = [] (auto& in, std::istream& is = std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(is, in);
        return  is.fail()
                || !std::regex_match(in, Letters)
                || in.size() == 1
                || std::isdigit(in[0])
                || std::isalpha(in[in.size() - 1])
                || !(is_Cell_type(in) != is_RC_type(in));
    };

    const auto handle_input = conditional<std::is_integral<Input>::value>(int_input, string_input);

    do
    {
        std::cout << std::forward<Prompt>(prompt) << std::flush;

        is_not_valid = handle_input(input);

        if (is_not_valid)
        {
            std::cout << Error;
        }

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
    } while (is_not_valid);

    return input;
}

int main()
{
    auto n = read_input<unsigned int>("Enter a number of entries: ");

    std::cout << "\n\n\tWelcome\n\n";

    do
    {
        const auto word = read_input<std::string>("Enter your choice: ");

        if (is_RC_type(word))
        {
            const auto index = word.find_first_of("C");
            assert(index != std::string::npos);
            const auto row = word.substr(1, index - 1);
            const auto col = word.substr(index + 1);

            auto c = string_to_int(col.cbegin(), col.cend());
            std::string result;

            do

                result =  static_cast<char>('A' + c % 26 - 1) + result;
            while (c /= 26);

            std::cout << "\n\nResult: " << result << row << "\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            const auto index = word.find_first_of("0123456789");
            assert(index != std::string::npos);
            const auto row = word.substr(index);
            const auto col = word.substr(0, index);
            int c = 0;
            for (const auto& ch : col)
            {
                c = 26 * c + (ch - 'A' + 1);
            }

            std::cout << "\n\nResult: R" << row << "C" << c << "\n\n";
        }
    } while (--n);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### last iterator could be const

I am personaly using `const` whenever possible.

```
int string_to_int(std::string::const_iterator first, const std::string::const_iterator last)
```

### unnecessary typename

You might skip the typename from

```
const typename std::string::value_type sign = *first;
```

or since `std::string` is `std::basic_string<char>` you might just use `char`

```
const char sign = *first;
```

### using regex

Have you considered using `std::regex_match` for `is_RC_type()` and `is_Cell_type()` implementation?

I guess regexes of interest might look like this

```
std::regex cell("[A-Z]+[0-9]+");
std::regex rc("R[0-9]+C[0-9]+");
```

### single responsibility principle

Using template `read_input()` for two different purposes (getting line count and getting coordinates) is a bad idea. It is unnecesarilly obfuscating underlying logic here:

```
static_assert((std::is_integral<Input>::value && !std::numeric_limits<Input>::is_signed)
|| std::is_same<std::decay_t<Input>, std::string>::value, "type not supported!\n");
```

or here:

```
const auto handle_input = conditional<std::is_integral<Input>::value>(int_input, string_input);
```

I would strongly recommend using two simple separate functions (or a function and template function).

### separating conversion logic

I would rather separate logic of RC <-> cell format conversions from main to standalone functions.

### error handling

You are not interested in handling any exception that might be thrown? (As soon as you start using `std::string` that might happen.)